# How can I transfer a file from Gmail using an app script by POSTing to a remote server

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

I'm using google apps scripting to write some addons to link gmail (or g suite email) to our crm system. 
My current issue is trying to take a selected attachment, POST to a php script on a remote server which recreates the file (and goes from there to integrate into our crm).

Details of the code etc is below though in essence the file obviously isn't transferring correctly so something is wrong in the way the file is being received, or saved locally. The filesize is different and it won't open. So for example I select a PDF in the email which is 640k and the resulting file created on my server is over 1mb

I've setup my script with a card which includes a radio list of attachments. A button in the card attempts to post the file contents to the remote server where a receiving PHP script just saves it as a local file.

1. Getting attachment list to produce radio buttons:

   `var attachmenttosave = CardService.newSelectionInput().setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.RADIO_BUTTON).setTitle("Selected Attachment").setFieldName("attachmenttosave");
       for(var i = 0; i < attachments.length; i++) {
           var attachment=attachments[i];
           attachmenttosave.addItem(attachment.getName(),i,false);
       }`
2. code which gets the attachment and POSTs to remote server:

```
    var accessToken = e.messageMetadata.accessToken;
    var accessToken = e.messageMetadata.accessToken;
    GmailApp.setCurrentMessageAccessToken(accessToken);
    var messageId = e.messageMetadata.messageId;
    var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
    var atc=e['formInput'].attachmenttosave;
    var attachments=message.getAttachments(); 
    var fn=attachments[parseInt(atc)].getName();            
    var blob=attachments[parseInt(atc)].getAs(attachments[parseInt(atc)].getContentType());
    var url="https://remote.server";

    var payload={"typ":"GS_SaveAttachmentToCase","email":encodeURIComponent(user),"fn":encodeURIComponent(fn), 'att':(blob)};
    var options={"method":"POST","payload":payload,"followRedirects":true,"muteHttpExceptions":true};
    var result=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);  
    var data = result.getContentText();    
    return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder().setNotification(CardService.newNotification().setText(data).setType(CardService.NotificationType.INFO)).build();
```

3. Receiving PHP script:

`

```
function GS_SaveAttachmentToCase(){
$fn=urldecode($_POST['fn']);
$fp = fopen("GS/" .$fn, "w+");
fwrite($fp, (utf8_decode ($_POST['att'])));
fclose($fp);
echo "done";
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

ok did some more research and solved this.

1. get the attachment contents using

`blob=attachments[parseInt(atc)].getBytes();`

2. in the receiving php script

`fwrite($fp, (base64_decode ($_POST['att'])));`